# Blazor wasm error "object reference not set to an instance of an object" that makes no sense

Tags: blazor-webassembly

Keeping it short, I have this code:

```
            Console.WriteLine($"A: {RequiredDataSetColumnTypes.Count()}");
            Console.WriteLine($"B: {RequiredDataSetColumnTypes == null}");
            Console.WriteLine($"C: {RequiredDataSetColumnTypes.Where(x=>x.DataSetColumnTypeId== 0).Count()}");
```

and this is the output in the dev tools console:

[image]

So this variable RequiredDataSetColumnTypes isn't null, it is a list with 2 objects inside it, but then if I try and filter it down it is saying object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I'm totally baffled by it.

Comment: What about ``DataSetColumnTypeId`` field/property of ``RequiredDataSetColumnTypes`` ? Maybe this is null?

Comment: Above line 3 add ` var result = RequiredDataSetColumnTypes.Where(x=>x.DataSetColumnTypeId== 0).Count();` and then put a break on that line and check what `result` is.